# Git stash pop on master branch

Tags: git, github, git-stash

I have two branches master and development. I stashed on master e.g.

```
git stash
git checkout development
```

Now, I was on development branch but by mistake I popped the stash

```
git stash pop
```

And now it shows conflicts. I reset the git using this:

```
git reset HEAD
```

But it is still showing conflicts. I need my stash back in master branch also. How can i fix this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undoing accidental git stash pop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543519/undoing-accidental-git-stash-pop)

Answer (score 2):

`git reset HEAD` won't touch the working tree, just the index. Effectively, it'll just unstage staged files because `HEAD` is where your current branch is already anyway (that's the definition of HEAD).

`git reset --hard HEAD` will fix the working tree to reflect `HEAD`.

If a `git pop` doesn't apply cleanly, the stash should have been kept.

**From man git-stash:**

> Applying the state can fail with conflicts; in this case, it is not removed from the stash list. You need to resolve the conflicts by hand and call git stash drop manually afterwards.

So just do:

```
git checkout master
git stash pop 
#or `git stash apply` if you don't want to drop the stash even if it does apply cleanly
```

Comment: is there any way to get the lost stash

Comment: If you got conflicts, the stash should have been kept, i.e., it shouldn't be lost.

Comment: If it is gone, you should be able to find it in the [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

Comment: You can use 'git stash list' to see if the stashed changes are there.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in the **git stash manual** using:

```
git stash --help
```

It has a section on what to do in case you clear/drop stashes by accident. This will help in understanding what is to be done in that case.

```
Recovering stashes that were cleared/dropped erroneously
   If you mistakenly drop or clear stashes, they cannot be recovered through the normal safety mechanisms. However, you can try the
   following incantation to get a list of stashes that are still in your repository, but not reachable any more:

       git fsck --unreachable |
       grep commit | cut -d\  -f3 |
       xargs git log --merges --no-walk --grep=WIP
```