# Switched Branch After .gitignore and lost .gitinored files

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-branch, missing-data

I am new to git, so sorry if this question has already been answered. I'm having trouble finding the answer to this.

I wanted to ignore a set of files that had never been committed before for a commit and used the github app to select them and ignore them. I switched to another branch for a while and when I returned to my branch, my ignored files were gone.

Are these files deleted?

I used    git checkout to switch back to the branch and then    git status --ignored . My missing files are not there.

Comment: Git doesn't delete files. Use the command `git ls-files` and check if your files are listed.

Comment: I tried it and I didn't see my files. I'm on a mac, and I was able to find messages.sassc, and my other files through that search. The "c" on the end is not a normal part of the extension though.

Comment: `git status` shows your files?

Comment: Oh, sorry I meant I found those files in finder. Finder shows the weird files.

Comment: But they are under your repository? They just changed the name?

Comment: I just figured out that those files are from the Rails cache of the app I'm working on.

Comment: `git status` doesn't show your files?

Comment: It shows other ignored files, but not the ones that had not been committed before.

Comment: `git rev-list --objects --all | grep messages.sass` shows any result?

Comment: that doesn't show anything.

Comment: It seems that your files were completely deleted. I don't know if it is a feature or bug. Maybe you can ask this in git main list. http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#git

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. It's at the point that the work is more important than recovering it. 

I did a "brain dump" while the work was still fresh in my head to churn out again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using `git reflog --all` to get the SHA code from when the Github App automatically stashed your ignored files before switching to the other branch.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8865242/2970321.

For example, I fetched a pull request (`/pr/364`) using the app (SHA `2ba129d`).  Before I switched back to `gh-pages`, it stashed my ignored files (SHA `36edfc6`).

[image: finding the SHA code of a dropped stash]

So to recover, all I needed to do was:

`git checkout 36edfc6`

My files magically reappeared, and I was able to safely stash them manually somewhere else before switching back to `gh-pages` again.

Comment: `--all` not `-all`

Comment: @tenprint thanks! You should have enough reputation to be able to suggest an edit directly (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Comment: Hero! You saved me ;)

Answer (score 1):

`git` doesn't delete files it doesn't care about unless specifically told to do so (by `checkout -f` in some cases of checking out, or `clean`). As `git` knows nothing about them, it can't resurecct them either. Use `git stash` before moving around and doing possibly damaging stuff. Consider carefully which files go into `.gitignore`, add *all* non-automatically-generated files to version control.

Comment: It would seem (at least in recent versions of the github app) that ignored files are automatically stashed when you switch branches.  See my answer.

Comment: "add all non-automatically-generated files to version control." Yes! The only exception might be really huge files like database backups -- in which case it's best to store it in an entirely different folder (or a permanently ignored subfolder).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you ignored the files in branch `A`, then switched to branch `B` but didn't ignore the files there.

If you ignore the files only in branch `A` but not in branch `B`, then they get deleted when switching back from `B` to `A`. However, they should reappear if you switch back  from `A` to `B`.

This is normal git behavior if you checkout from any branch `X` to `Y`, all files that are not in branch `Y` but in branch `X` are removed. If a file is ignored in `Y` but not in `X`, then you have this case.

To prevent your files from being deleted, you may add them in the `.gitignore` file in your other branch `B`.