# Undo git stash pop on dirty working tree

Tags: git, git-stash

This seems very foolish mistake, I just did a `git stash pop` on a dirty working tree. I do not know any way of keeping the desired changes and undoing the `stash pop`. Does one exist? Or such a mistake is unforgivable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you still have that stash's SHA1, you can generate a patch from it (`git format-patch SHA1`) and apply the patch in reverse (`git apply -R filename.patch`).

If you lost the SHA1, see [How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git)

Comment: How do you create a patchfile out of the format-patch command ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for merges; when I did `git stash pop` on my dirty working directory, it merged the stashed changes, so `git format-patch SHA1` didn't do anything. Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: It doesn't work for me either, when changes from popped stash are merged, creation of the patch gives me empty patch file. Does anybody know how to workaround this ?

Answer (score 1):

`git stash pop` does 2 things: `git stash apply` and `git stash drop`.  If you can undo the `drop`, using [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git), then you'd just have to undo the `apply`. I'm not sure how to do this, <s>but you might look into `git rebase`</s>. but adl does.