# How to retrieve stashed changes

Tags: git

I stashed my changes because I had to pull. However, I forgot to pop my changes before I turned off my laptop. I tried the command `git stash list` to see if my stashed changes is there but I can't find it. How can I retrieve it? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git

Comment: Shouldn't matter if you turned off your laptop or not.  Stashed changes should still be in the repository until you remove them (either with `git pop` or `git stash clear`).

Comment: Be sure you are in your git repo ;) As a stash is a commit, it is stored by Git even if you switched your computer off.

Comment: @Dmitri: it is not a dropped stash.

Answer (score 3):

To apply the recently pushed stash use:

`git stash apply`