# Recover stashes that were accidentally cleared

Tags: git, git-stash

This morning while moving quickly from branch to branch, I had to stash my changes.  In my haste, I issued a

```
git stash clear
```

-- as my stash list was rather long. In the list of stashes that I cleared was some work I need to recover.  Is there a way to recover it?  The stash in question was saved using:

```
git stash save "my notes here"
```

Not sure that really helps. Is there any hope?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

As any stash is like a commit, but handled differently, you'll find them in the reflog. You can access the reflog via `git reflog`, where you get a list of all commit objects recently made.

Comment: I am finding that I need to use `git reflog --all` to see anything regarding stashes.  Sadly, what I get back is only the very last stash that was created (or 'pop').  When I navigate to the '/.git/refs' folder and examine the 'stash'  file in Textmate, indeed -- it only show that single (and lonely SHA1).  It would seem to me that `git stash clear` is destructive, and unrecoverable.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Did you check the link in the comment on your question? That might help.

Comment: thanks @Femaref -- it also did not help (thanks @Ashfame). Turns out my files were not tracked -- and I believe that was the crux of my problem.