# How to recover the index after a git stash / git stash pop?

Tags: git, git-stash

After adding some changes to the index with git add -p, I then issued a git stash but forgot to add --keep-index. Then I stupidly did a git stash pop, and all my changes to the index were gone. Is there a way to recover the index to the state before the git stash?

Comment: Stashing usually saves both the index and the changes in the working directory separately, so popping the stash should restore the index as well?

Comment: @poke That's not what happened unfortunately, the index was emptied by git stash and remained so after the git stash pop. Maybe if I had done a git stash pop --index instead it would have been restored, but I didn't :/

Comment: @poke first part correct, second part incorrect. `--index` must be added to the `git stash apply|pop` for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you've just done `git stash pop`, the last line in the output is:

```
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949)
```

If you've lost it, see [How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/91795) to find the commit hash.

Once you have the hash, **either**:

- Drop all current changes (applied stash):

  `git reset --hard`

  And reapply the stash using its id, this time with index:

  `git stash apply ca82a6d --index`
- Reset only the index, the point here is that the index is saved as a second parent of the stash:

  `git reset ca82a6d^2 .`

  Notice the dot at the end. If you don't specify it, it'll also move HEAD to the index (the index will appear as a commit). In this case run `git reset --soft HEAD@{1}` to return the HEAD to its previous position.

Answer (score 7):

This will do the job:

```
git stash apply --index
```

---

**Edit**: Considering the index is already lost, you should run a `git fsck --unreachable` and inspect the latest commits it gives. You must be able to see your lost index there. After that you can `git cherry-pick` it.

Comment: Neat! Stashes do keep a separate state of index and working directory. I had no idea of this.

Comment: This also works with "pop": `git stash pop --index`