# Git: Reverting a git reset --hard

Tags: git

Just ran a git reset --h by accident. I had lots of modified files, and a few new files.

Previous to the reset, I hadn't created a commit, so I can't look in the reflog and revert back to a commit.

Tell me there's a way I can get these files back?! :(

Comment: I can tell you that there's a way to get those files back, but unless you've got copies elsewhere or backups or something, I'd probably be lying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot get those modifications back.

The only exception would be if you had recently stashed and unstashed them, in which case you could read [How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git).

Comment: Unfortunately no stash :| That'll teach me for being too cocky :|

Comment: I have, however, kept VS open... so I've been able to "Ignore Changes" on the reload prompt, and re-save a hell of a lot of the files I had open, so it's not ALL bad. Hopefully I haven't missed anything major...

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the files to be staged before you reset? If so then the following would work:

`git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --unreachable  HEAD`

That will show you something like:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
unreachable blob 97145fe866b78bf0ff0d59b0b4d6b69f1446faa9
```

You can then say

```
git cat-file blob 97145fe866b > file
```

That will then add it back to the working tree.

Unfortunately if you did not add or commit the files there is no way to get back unstaged changes after a reset --hard.

Comment: No, I'd literally just finished my work and was about to add them.