# git stash file reset to first commit

Tags: git, version-control

I've been working on a project for a while and used git from the beginning. After a few commits, I made a change to a file which I realised was unnecessary. In an attempt to discard those changes and return to the state of the latest commit, I used:

```
git stash save --keep-index
```

which gave me the output:

> Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: cc91857 fixed animation bug
>   HEAD is now at cc91857 fixed animation bug

and dropped the stash by typing

```
git stash drop
```

Output:

> Dropped refs/stash@{0} (dfb694b90757d8d25318b09da4f5dad2f3be20a6)

However, instead of changing the edited file to the state of the last commit, it was changed to the state of the initial commit, although my head remained at the same commit. To my horror, I have discovered that the file that contained changes I originally wanted to drop now appears to have remained unchanged between the first commit and the most recent one. Other files are not affected.

Is there any way to reset the file to the state of my last recent commit?

Comment: possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate

Comment: The correct option is `--keep-index` (not the hyphen). Are you sure you ran `git stash save --keep index` (without hyphen) or is it a typo?

Comment: That was a typo, edited it. Thanks

Comment: I've edited your question slightly, for clarity; feel free to change it if you think my edit is inaccurate. Because the `git stash` commands you report using cannot affect your commits, it looks like the file in question really hasn't changed since the first commit. Perhaps the commit you're trying to get back to is on a different branch to the one you're on right now..

Comment: The accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git
fixed the issue.

Comment: @JonaSc Cool. Should we close this question as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git, then?

Answer (score 0):

To recover the stash,

```
touch .git/refs/stash     # make sure stash reflog exists, see update-ref docs
git update-ref -m "$(git show -s --format:%s dfb694b9)" refs/stash dfb694b9
git checkout master       # (where you took the stash originally)
git stash apply
```