# IntelliJ Version Control History Log

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Some of my stashes seemed to have disappeared. I would like to be able to backtrace what happened from the console commands.

Is there a way to store or retrieve a local log file of the version control transactions from IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might give [git reflog](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) a try. Command line, but seems to be supported by Tortoise git.

This will not give you the log of Intellij, but you should be able to recover the recent stashes at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve lost stash from intellij
Try to open git bash and follow instructions to recover stash drop with reflog:
[How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git)

After you'll recover the stashed you will be able to see it again in intellij.