# Windows equivalent of this gitk Linux command

Tags: linux, windows, git, powershell, awk

From this SO: [How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git)

I would like to convert this Linux command to the Windows equivalent or maybe this is command is syntacially correct for Windows, not sure about the `$` and the `|` :

```
gitk --all $( git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}' )
```

I have tried running this cmd on my Windows Git Shell, Powershell and Cmd.exe, with my `cd` being a git directory, with Cmd.exe:

[image]

On Git Shell:

[image]

Which gives me the following error:

[image]

I have installed gawk: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

And added `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin` to my `Path` Environment Variables

Comment: Why did you remove the `awk` bit? It matters. It is filtering the output of `git fsk --no-reflog` to only the third field of lines that contain `dangling commit` on them. Which, presumably, is just the commit hashes. So that `gitk --all` doesn't get arguments it doesn't understand.

Comment: I thought awk was a Linux only cmd, just discovering GnuWin32

Comment: Or maybe I need "gawk" installed on my Windows machine http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

Comment: You certainly might not have awk on Windows but git-bash does I believe as do any number of other things.

Comment: git-bash has awk available. cygwin does as well, Where are you running this `gitk` command?

Comment: I have updated my question, I have tried running this 'gitk' command in Git Shell and cmd.exe, see the images I uploaded for you

Comment: awk is in the `git\bin` directory (where git itself is in `git\cmd`). You might be able to just add that to your `PATH` but I don't know that that's a good idea. You can try running it via full path in that command line call though.

Comment: Did you restart the shell (and possibly Windows) after modifying `PATH`? If they haven't seen the updated path they still won't be able to find awk. A full path in the command line should work though.

Comment: You should be able to replace `| awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}'` with something like `| ? {$_ -match 'dangling commit'} | % {$_.Split()[2]}` in PowerShell.

Comment: if you're going the `gawk` route, make sure to change your cmd-line from `awk` to `gawk`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Windows PowerShell equivalent:

`gitk --all $(git fsck --no-reflog | Select-String "(dangling commit )(.*)" | %{ $_.Line.Split(' ')[2] })`

Comment: Thank you! Saved a whole days worth of work lost with a GitKraken stash poping accident :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I had to install gawk/awk: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

Then I updated my `Path` Environment Variable: `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\`

Then I had to restart my computer to refresh Environment Variables.

Then I could run the gitk cmd, without any changes, works fine on a Windows machine:

```
gitk --all $( git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}' )
```

But it has to be in Windows Git Shell, the cmd did not work from Windows cmd.exe.