# How to recover master branch's git stash after rebase?

Tags: git

RESOLVED

I was working on branch A and stashed some changes.

I checked out branch B and ran `git rebase A`. (There were a few merge conflicts I had to fix.)

I checked out branch A and all my stashes are gone.**
edit: `git stash list` and `pop` returned nothing. However my stash was still under .git/logs/stash and was recoverd with `git stash apply HASH`

Is there any way to recover them? I tried `git reflog --all` and it doesn't list any stashes. .git/logs/stash is a ~30char hash string but I'm not sure if those are the right changes, how to check, or how to apply them.

If they're gone forever I'd like to at least understand why it happened. I didn't expect changes on branch B to affect branch A so it seems I'm missing a key concept here :/

Comment: When you say "all my stashes are gone", do you mean that `git stash list` returns nothing?

Comment: Anything helpful in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git ?

Comment: @shoover : Yes, it turned out the stash was there. Thank goodness--the hash string I mentioned was the right one, I'd assumed it was old because stash list was empty and git stash pop returned an error. And I checked that thread before asking :)