# Retrieve popped stash in an aborted git rebase edit

Tags: git, rebase

I'm an idiot.  I stashed some changes to put them in a previous commit, so I rebased interactive, edited the commit, popped the stash, then realized that this would cause problems with other commits so I should just make a new commit on top.  Aborted rebase and then attempted to pop the stash... which I no longer had.  I lost the stash in the aborted rebase!  Is there a way to get it back??

```
git stash
git rebase -i HEAD@{3}
(chose to edit HEAD@{2})
git stash pop
git rebase --abort
git stash pop
...
```

... aaaaand there's nothing to pop!

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/1440/stashing/12432/recover-a-dropped-stash#t=201611290743079506482

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git)

Comment: A stash is just a commit (two commits, actually), so the reflog should be of some use here.  Just find your stash commit, then use it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you still have your console open or have the hash of your stash from some other source, the following topic might help.

[How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git)