# how to redo discarded local changes in git?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reflog

Let have a file `a` tracked by git and modified locally.
Moreover, that file was in the stash too.

Then:

If you did it `git stash pop`, see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git)

If accidentally you did only this `git checkout a` you've lost.

That discards all changes in a file.

How to undo this operation?

I don't see this operation in `reflog`.

Stash after pop doesn't exist (not listed), but does any of that history is available somewhere in `.git` directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git looks like it might be just what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reflog` only keeps track of when a tip of branch has been updated so I wouldn't expect to see your changes there.

From the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog):

> Reference logs, or "reflogs", record when the tips of branches and
>   other references were updated in the local repository.

Sorry to say that using `checkout` in this situation means those changes are lost.

`stash` can be a safer alternative.

EDIT:

If this loss is severe, you can potentially do some digging by looking at @jthill's comment on the original question

Comment: that file *was* in poped stash, is it change anything ?

Comment: @ups popping things off of your stash stack removes them from that stack so I think it's still lost...however if you had used "apply" rather than "pop" it would still be retrievable. Are you sure your changes were not part of a previous commit?