# I called git stash pop three times for no reason. How do I undo this?

Tags: git

I have gotten in the habit of using the `git stash`/`git stash pop` feature as I get random requests to make fixes at work while I'm in the middle of doing something on a different branch.

This morning I decided to start with a project I was working on on a different branch. I didn't remember if anything was stashed or not so I called git stash pop. Inexplicably, I called it twice more. I have no idea what I did, but I want to undo it. What should I do exactly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `git stash pop` only changes your working directory; it does not commit any changes to your repository.  You can restore the state of your working directory to the state it was in before running `git stash pop` by running:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

This reverts your working directory to the current `HEAD` of your repository.  You will have lost your stashes, though.

From a workflow perspective, don't be afraid to just commit your changes to your branch rather than using `git stash`: you can always edit the commit before you share it with anybody.

Comment: Also! If you are nervous about trying random commands suggested by people on stackoverflow, remember that you can always make a copy of your repository to test with (`cp -a myrepo myrepo-for-testing`).

Comment: **NOTE : you will loose all that was stashed**. Its already mentioned in the ans, but I think it should be highlighted as, the OP stashed them because because he wanted to keep them.

Answer (score 0):

You have lost your `stashes`, and I don't think there's any easier way to bring them back. As far as cleaning your working directory is concerned, just do

```
git stash # again

or 

git checkout -f # if you're not interested in keeping any stash changes
```

As a suggestion, always prefer `git stash apply` over `git pop`

Comment: Could `git fsck` not be used to recover the stash objects?

Comment: Yes,  it's possible to stash hash, however as I said there is no easier way. You may consult this answer if you're interested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git