# How to resolve git stash conflicts?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge-conflict

I have a repository where a `stash` is applied. However now the code looks likes this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
        wp_redirect( set_url_scheme( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'https' ) );
        exit();
    } else {
        wp_redirect( 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
=======
        wp_safe_redirect( set_url_scheme( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'https' ) );
        exit();
    } else {
        wp_safe_redirect( 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
>>>>>>> dev-wip
```

The problem is now the `stash` is not showing in the `git`. And it does not show any conflicts. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing is how Git represents a merge conflict in a source code file.  The markers `<<<<<<<`, `=======`, and `>>>>>>>` are merge *conflict* markers, and they separate the two versions coming from each parent in the merge.  I am guessing that the version `dev-wip` is coming from your Stash.  If you want to use that version, then just edit your file so the snippet above looks like this:

```
wp_safe_redirect( set_url_scheme( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'https' ) );
    exit();
} else {
    wp_safe_redirect( 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```

Then, save the file and finish applying the stash.  You may want a version which is a combination of the two shown to you.  In that case, make the appropriate edit.

Note that you should generally lean towards doing `git stash apply` rather than `git stash pop`, because the latter *removes* the stash from the stack, and it won't be available again later should something go wrong.

Comment: But the problem is that I have more than 500 files like this. :( :(

Comment: @JanakaDombawela Then you might be doing something wrong, or perhaps you need to change your approach.  With 500 files in conflict, it looks like your stash is massively out of date with the current branch.

Comment: @JanakaDombawela Might be the moment to consider going back in history, either with a reset to a specified commit or with a reflog before the stash pop.

Comment: If there is a need to recover the stash, then https://stackoverflow.com/q/89332/2311167 could help.