# Git: Is there a way to check previously stashed code?

Tags: git

I have lost a lot of work, which was not staged. However I did stash it, and then unstash it, before losing it. Does git save this info anywhere?

Edit: I still had the dropped stash reference ID in my terminal, so was able to recover using Dolda's suggestion in [How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on what the flow was? How can I **reproduce** your problem? At a guess, I think you have done: `git stash; git stash pop; git reset HEAD --hard` ?

Comment: @TomLord Unfortunately I can't remember  exactly how I lost the work, but I am assuming this happened: I stashed my work, went to a different branch, then back to my working branch, unstashed, and the changes were not updated in my editor. Then I must have saved my editor, which basically deleted the unstashed work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, that has the answer I was looking for :)

Comment: This isn't exactly a solution to your problem, but in future I would suggest committing the changes to the branch, rather than stashing them. (You can always later reset/squash the commit.)

Comment: Stashing is only the best solution, I find, when you don't yet know which branch the changes belong on.