# Eclipse Git Integration: how to recover deleted stash?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I think I accidentally deleted a stash of mine in Eclipse. I still have the project itself. Is there a way to recover the deleted stash WITHOUT using a command line? My workstation just has the Git integration for Eclipse to work with.

(There are other similar questions, but their cases are a tad different.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that  I know of: [restoring a deleted stash usually involve `git fsck --unreachable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5879550/6309).

> My workstation just has the Git integration for Eclipse to work with.

Assuming Windows, even as a non-admin, you can add Git in command line through the portable archive [`PortableGit-2.20.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.20.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.20.0-64-bit.7z.exe) that you can uncompress anywhere you want.

Comment: Used that download and misc. commands on the page you linked, found the hash in a few minutes and was able to recover my stash. Thanks a ton!