# Revert git file back to state before it was popped from stash

Tags: git

I had some stashed code that I popped and made some changes to one of the popped files.

Is there a way to get that file state back to the state it was when it was stashed? Meaning discarding all changes on that specific file since `git stash pop` was executed.

Comment: In general no, there isn't, because once you pop something from the stash, it is basically gone forever.  For future reference, you should use `git stash apply`, which _doesn't_ pop the commit from the stack.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is one reason why I don't like the stash. I tend to make a temporary branch with my local changes and rebase or cherry pick it where I need it. It's more work but I have full control and full revertability. But I realize that doesn't help you, since you've presumably already done the pop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git)