# Can I recover changes after git stash pop followed by git checkout .?

Tags: git

I accidentally run `git checkout .` and lost the changes I made on my local repo.

I remember that once I had those changes stashed but I used `git stash pop` to retrieve them (sadly, I didn't know about `git stash apply` at the time), and now I can not find these changes on my stash.

I searched on SO but most of the answers were for `git stash apply`, or told me to retrieve the SHA-1 outputted after the `git stash pop`, but I don't have that information.

Is there any way to recover my changes?

Comment: When you call `git stash pop`, you apply the changes for the stash at the top of the stack _and_ you also remove/pop those changes from the stash.  So, if you really used pop, then the changes are probably gone forever.  Moving forward, if there be _any_ chance that you would need to use the changes more than once, then _always_ use `git stash apply`.

Comment: If the terminal where the pop was run is still open, the id of that stash object (reported on the execution) can still be used with `git stash apply`

Comment: Unfortunately, some days passed between the `git stash pop` and the `git checkout .`, the terminal from pop was not open anymore. I was thinking that maybe some reflog magic could save me but I guess I'll just have to think on my changes and write them again. :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git

Comment: Unfortunately, `git stash pop` removes the reflog entry—in fact, the pushed stash stack is nothing *but* reflog entries.

Comment: Amazing! executing command `git fsck --no-reflog | select-string 'dangling commit' | foreach { $bits = $_ -split ' '; echo $bits[2];}` shown the stash SHA-1! Then I could retrieve it with `git stash apply {SHA}`