# Git stash pop returns "fatal: log for refs/stash is empty"

Tags: git

I'm new to git and been working off master the entire time. I wanted to pull some changes from master but save local changes so I ran:

```
$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state wip on master: c13af16 added banked hours process  
$ git pull  
already up to date
$ git stash pop  
fatal: log for ref/stash is empty
```

Despite this all the changes I made since my last commit are gone. I ran **git reset --hard** and the changes are still gone.

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git i think the problem is related.

Comment: That's definitely bad: `git stash` (which means push or save, depending on the particular version of Git you're running) says it made a stash, but then `git stash pop` says there's something wrong with the `refs/stash` reference that keeps track of stashes. What version of Git are you running?