# How to recover a deleted stash from git tower

Tags: git, git-tower

I accidently deleted my stash from git tower. I seen solutions to recover stash those deleted via terminal but no solution for this problem. Can anyone help

Comment: There should not be much difference. Could you find the hash of your deleted stash with `git fsck` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git ?

Answer (score 1):

Undoing a deleted stash is not (yet) supported out of the box in Tower, so you'll need to drop to Terminal. A way to find the missing stash(es) would be the following command:

`$ git fsck --no-reflog --connectivity-only | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}'`

You can check if a commit is a stash with the command `git show <HASH>` and store it as a stash again with `git stash store <HASH>`.