# How to discard stash pop in Git without dropping my uncommitted changes?

Tags: git, git-stash

I've made some uncommitted changes before executing `git stash pop`. How can I discard `stash pop` without dropping my uncommitted changes?

`git reset --hard HEAD` will reset my local changes.

Comment: You can't; you popped the stash, so it isn't there anymore.  Now your changes and the changes from the stash are one and the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you run `git stash pop` the changes get applied to your working tree and the stash is removed. Depending on how much has changed between the time you ran `pop` and now, there is a chance you could recover the stash from the commit logs (stashing does create some commit references), but it might not be easy...

First, follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/91795/6689725) to try and get the hash for the stash commit you are looking to recover. Once it's found, create a branch with it (I'll call it `stash_data`, and assume we are starting from branch `master`):

```
git branch stash_data [stash hash ID]
```

That branch should now have just the content of the stash and none of the other changes. Now create a new branch to commit all of the uncommitted changes-- both the stash **and** non-stash (I'll call it `combined_data`).

```
[on `master` branch, with all changes]
git checkout -b combined_data
git add [your files]
git commit -m "preparing to revert a stash pop"
```

Now there are 3 branches. One with the stash changes applied (`stash_data`), one with all changes applied (`combined_data`) and one at baseline (`master`). Apply the diff between `stash_data` and `master` to `combined_data`:

```
[still on branch `combined_data`]
git diff stash_data master | git apply
```

`combined_data` should now have only those changes that **were not** in the stash, and `stash_data` should have only the change that **were** in the stash.