# Accidentally removed stash in Github Desktop - Don't know how to get it back

Tags: github, github-desktop

I meant to stash my changes so I could see what my project was like before my changes, but when I went to bring it back I had accidentally overridden my stash. Not sure if it can be brought back.

I tried 'git fsck --unreachable', but there is a lot to sort through and I didn't see it anywhere

Up late trying to fix it, any help would be appreciated so I don't have to pull an all-nighter to redo my work.

Comment: Run `git stash list` from the Git bash, and do this immediately.  Do you see your stash there?  I have no experience using GitHub desktop, but in pure Git, you can't "overwrite" a Git stash.  You _can_ pop a stash, removing it from the stack, but, other than this, a stash will continue to live in your Git memory.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I probably already doomed myself. Already discarded what was in the new accidental stash which may have been a mistake. I'm not seeing the stash in the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Got it back with https://dev.to/meduzen/recover-a-lost-git-stash-in-two-steps-569

Thanks for the help though, it's much appreciated how quick you were to respond.

I'm up way too late, going to bed before I break something else by accident.

Comment: Don't give any credit...it is 2pm here, and I've had a bunch of coffee `:-)`