# Visual Studio Undo Drop Stash

Tags: visual-studio

By mistake I pressed on drop and now I dont have my changes is there any way to bring the dropped stash in Visual Studio?

1. I did changes to the project
2. I stashed the changes
3. I pulled code from the remote repo
4. I pressed on Drop in the stash menu

How to undo the drop?

Comment: VS should prompt with a confirmation to drop.  It is too easy to fall into this trap!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**This is what worked for me:**

**Answer here:** [How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git)

1. In the project folder right mouse click and click on Gitbash here
   [image]
2. In the GIT console window: **git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}'**
3. **gitk --all $( git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}' )**
4. Right Click on the commit and click new Branch
   [image]
5. Now in Visual Studio the new branch can be opened and inspect the code
   [image]

Comment: You save my day. I thought I had lost all my today's code. Thank you so much!

Comment: I can't even begin to express my appreciation for this nugget to the git god who shared this. Thanks so much.