# Adding Only Untracked Files

Tags: git, git-add

One of the commands I find incredibly useful in Git is `git add -u` to throw everything but untracked files into the index. Is there an inverse of that?

Such as a way to add **only** the untracked files to the index *without identifying them individually*?

Comment: Regarding "throw everything but untracked files into the index", `.gitignore` is specifically engineered for that purpose, not `git add -u`.

Comment: Also, are you asking to add the untracked files while removing all the currently tracked ones, or are you asking to add the untracked files **on top** of the currently tracked ones (making everything tracked)?

Answer (score 318, accepted):

It's easy with `git add -i`. Type `a` (for "add untracked"), then `*` (for "all"), then `q` (to quit) and you're done.

To do it with a single command: `echo -e "a\n*\nq\n"|git add -i`

Comment: I was hoping there was something less, well, interactive, but it's certainly better than file by file. :-)

Comment: `echo -e "a\n*\nq\n"|git add -i`

Comment: @Mat thank you so is the complete command ----> git add -i a * q          ??

Comment: `Argument list too long`... so close!

Comment: What to do, I am also, getting Argument list too long @Simeon

Comment: @Lion789 See my answer on how to do this on Windows here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446640/adding-only-untracked-files/40172072#40172072

Comment: Worth noting `git add -i` also allows wildcards as parameters, so you can do `git add -i '*.xml'` to only add new xml files.

Comment: Don't forget commit after adding untrack files ;)

Comment: I get a `Huh` after  the a

Comment: For me with git 2.21.0 is was `git add -i` then `4` to add untracked then `*` for all then `q` to quit

Comment: `gir add -i` then `4` then `1-300` repeat until done, if there are many untracked files

Comment: if  the command is too difficult to remember, you can create: aliases - either in your .bashrc file (or equivalent shell), or you can create git aliases. edit: consider the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13427000/4880924

Answer (score 46):

`git ls-files -o --exclude-standard` gives untracked files, so you can do something like below ( or add an alias to it):

```
git add $(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard)
```

Comment: alias gau="git ls-files -o --exclude-standard | xargs -i git add '{}'" works for me

Comment: git ls-files --help is quite a useful read:

`-o, --others`
`Show other (i.e. untracked) files in the output`

Comment: Nice, however I believe this will only give you the untracked files for the current directory. You would need to use pborenstein's answer above to retrieve a list of untracked files for the entire working tree.

Answer (score 22):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but I've found this quite helpful:

```
git add -AN
```

Will add all files to the index, but without their content. Files that were untracked now behave as if they were tracked. Their content will be displayed in `git diff`, and you can add then interactively with `git add -p`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - allows for `git commit -p` to walk through new files as well.

Answer (score 15):

I tried this and it worked :

```
git stash && git add . && git stash pop
```

`git stash` will only put all modified tracked files into separate stack, then left ones are untracked files. Then by doing `git add .` will stage all files untracked files, as required. Eventually, to get back all modified files from stack by doing `git stash pop`

Comment: that's really a nice way of doing it!

Answer (score 12):

You can add this to your ~/.gitconfig file:

```
[alias]
    add-untracked = !"git status --porcelain | awk '/\\?\\?/{ print $2 }' | xargs git add"
```

Then, from the commandline, just run:

```
git add-untracked
```

Comment: I like this approach, but it doesn't handle spaces in filenames.

Answer (score 12):

People have suggested piping the output of `git ls-files` to `git add` but this is going to fail in cases where there are filenames containing white space or glob characters such as `*`.

The safe way would be to use:

```
git ls-files -o --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 git add
```

where `-z` tells git to use `\0` line terminators and `-0` tells xargs the same. The only disadvantage of this approach is that the `-0` option is non-standard, so only some versions of `xargs` support it.

Answer (score 8):

`git ls-files` lists the files in the current directory. If you want to list untracked files from anywhere in the tree, this might work better:

```
git ls-files -o --exclude-standard $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
```

To add all untracked files in the tree:

```
git ls-files -o --exclude-standard $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) | xargs git add
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have thousands of untracked files (ugh, don't ask) then `git add -i` will not work when adding `*`. You will get an error stating `Argument list too long`.

If you then also are on Windows (don't ask #2 :-) and need to use PowerShell for adding all untracked files, you can use this command:

```
git ls-files -o --exclude-standard | select | foreach { git add $_ }
```

Comment: A more condensed version: `git ls-files -o --exclude-standard | % { git add $_ }`

Answer (score 1):

Lot of good tips here, but inside Powershell I could not get it to work.

I am a .NET developer and we mainly still use Windows OS as we haven't made use of .Net core and cross platform so much, so my everyday use with Git is in a Windows environment, where the shell used is more often Powershell and not Git bash.

The following procedure can be followed to create an aliased function for adding untracked files in a Git repository.

Inside your $profile file of Powershell (in case it is missing - you can run:
New-Item $Profile)

notepad $Profile

Now add this Powershell method:

```
function AddUntracked-Git() {
 &git ls-files -o --exclude-standard | select | foreach { git add $_ }
}
```

Save the $profile file and reload it into Powershell.
Then reload your $profile file with: 
. $profile

This is similar to the source command in *nix environments IMHO.

So next time you, if you are developer using Powershell in Windows against Git repo 
and want to just include untracked files you can run:

AddUntracked-Git

This follows the Powershell convention where you have verb-nouns.

Answer (score 1):

git add . *(add all files in this directory)*

git add -all *(add all files in all directories)*

git add -N can be helpful for for listing which ones for later....

Comment: [`git add -u`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--u) will add modified files not untracked

Answer (score -3):

To add all untracked files 
git command is

> git add -A

Also if you want to get more details about various available options , you can type command

> git add -i

instead of first command , with this you will get more options including option to add all untracked files as shown below :

> $ git add -i warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in README.txt. The
>   file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
>   warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package.json.
>
> *** Commands ***   1: status       2: update       3: revert       4: add untracked   5: patch        6: diff         7: quit         8:
>   help What now> a