# Git Command for adding (not committing) all new files in one shot

Tags: git, git-add

We are using Git as a revision control system for our Rails project.

Now, I have a bunch of untracked files in my application directory and I would like to add all those untracked files in one shot to the Git index. I referred to the Git documentation and I would like to check if I understood it correctly.

For adding all untracked files, the command is:

```
git add -A
```

OR

```
git add --all
```

Please correct me if it is correct or not. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yes, `git add --all` should add all untracked files at once. What's your question?

Comment: @Surya: I was not sure about it, that's why asked if it is correct or not. What about `git add -A`?

Comment: Would `git add .` work too ?

Comment: @AndrewC: I did a research, but couldn't find the given question. I think the way I've asked the question is different from the above question.

Comment: It's worded slightly different, but it's the same question.  Rob - "Is there a way to add only the untracked files to the index ", you - " I would like to add all those untracked files".  No ?

Answer (score 1):

You can either add tracked and untracked files, or only untracked files as follows.

Both of your examples add tracked and untracked files.

If you'd like to add *only* untracked files, you could launch Git's interactive mode:

```
$ git add -i
```

You can then choose to add untracked files by typing <kbd>a</kbd> and pressing <kbd>RETURN</kbd>. After that you can quit by typing <kbd>q</kbd> followed by <kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

[Also see this StackOverflow answer for more possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446640/adding-only-untracked-files).