# How To Add Untracked Files on Git?

Tags: git

I am having trouble adding untracked files or modified files on git. This is the message I am getting:

On branch homework110515
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

```
modified:   MarcoPortfolio (untracked content)
modified:   session2.2 (modified content)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Only Untracked Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446640/adding-only-untracked-files)

Answer (score 12):

You have pending changes in your workspace. To stage them for a commit you need to add them. Basically exactly what it says: "Changes not staged for commit". To stage changes you need to add them with the `add` command:

```
git add [file]
```

Typically I just add all the files in the working directory with:

```
git add .
```

At this point you can commit your changes with `git commit -m "[message]"`

Comment: @Marcode777 Can you do a `git status` and edit your question with the output?

Comment: Doesn't totally answer the question... how to add only untracked files, not including modified files -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/3801554/1388017

Comment: @dezman I disagree. The question states "adding untracked files or modified files."