# How to discard staged changes in git without effecting unstaged changes

Tags: git

In order to include some untracked files in my commit I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446640/adding-only-untracked-files) post and accidently added a lot of unwanted stuff. Now I have this situation in my repo.

```
2016-02-02 16:51 Unknown            o Staged changes <--- untracked files
2016-02-02 16:51 Unknown            o Unstaged changes <-- want to preserve
2016-01-04 17:01 XXXXX YYYYY        I [wool_task_conversion] [master] [origin/HEAD] [origin/master] First commit
```

I now want to bring back the untracked files in thier original position i.e. the unstaged area as before preserving the changes in unstaged area for tracked files.

Comment: if your files are `untracked` what would be their *original position*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the output of `git status` it actually answers this question:

```
Davids-Mac-Pro:DAD dhoelzer$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   t
```

So, simply executing `git reset HEAD <file>` will do what you are asking.

If you want to remove all staged changes while retaining the changes, the following should be correct:

```
 git reset HEAD -- .
```

This should be run from the root of your project.

Comment: I have 1000 files to reset. Should I do them one by one?

Comment: Updated to answer your comment.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Use,

`git reset` or `git reset --mixed`

> **--mixed**
>
> Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports
>   what has not been updated. **This is the default action**.

You can then accordingly stage the required files.