# Git diff doesn't show changes for new added files

Tags: git, git-diff, git-stage

First I did git status on my newly cloned repo

```
$ git status
On branch Test
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Now I copies a Test project from another Directory

```
$ git status
On branch Test
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        Test/

no thing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Following are the files

```
$ ls Test -a
./  ../  .classpath  .gitignore  .project  Test.class  Test.java
```

But git diff gives below result

```
$ git diff
```

Basically, nothing. 
But if I stage it and do the git diff -cached it shows as bellow

```
$ git diff --cached
diff --git a/Test/.classpath b/Test/.classpath
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..233be1d
--- /dev/null
+++ b/Test/.classpath
@@ -0,0 +1,6 @@
+<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
+<classpath>
+       <classpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
+       <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
+       <classpathentry kind="output" path=""/>
+</classpath>
diff --git a/Test/.gitignore b/Test/.gitignore
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..a9819ad
--- /dev/null
+++ b/Test/.gitignore
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+/Test.class
diff --git a/Test/.project b/Test/.project
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..b6bd205
....
```

How can I see above changes without staging it ( i.e. while copied folder is unstaged).

Please explain how git works here. Is it ever possible to see copied folder/file changes without first commit ?

Comment: Would `git add --intent-to-add Test ; git diff` (or `git add -N`) work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use git diff on untracked files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855767/can-i-use-git-diff-on-untracked-files)

Comment: @knitti That works, but  I was trying to find a way to do that without doing that every time I add a new file. because I do that a lot. Just a single small command. I don't know if that is only me or there are other who also don't want to go through all the trouble for new files.

Answer (score 2):

How about `git status --porcelain | grep -e '^??' | sed -e 's/^?? //g' | xargs less`?

You can see all untracked files by `less`.