# git diff with respect to working tree including untracked files without manually adding them first

Tags: git, diff

I have an old commit `A`. I am now at commit `B` = `HEAD` ≠ `A`, and want to compare the state of my working directory, *including* untracked files, with `A`.

The reason is that the currently untracked files were part of commit `A`, so they wouldn't show up in, and thus wouldn't clutter, the diff I desire.

As a workaround, I could manually `git add <all the untracked files>` before the diff and `git reset <all the untracked files>` after. However, there are many untracked files, and I would like to do this in a maximally atomic and robust way, as I am doing all of this in a script.

This question also concerns diff against untracked files: [Can I use git diff on untracked files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855767/can-i-use-git-diff-on-untracked-files)

However, the answers there require manual adding and later removing of untracked files, and I preferred a solution that does this more automatically and in an atomic way that is error-proof against interruptions in a scripted context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use git diff on untracked files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855767/can-i-use-git-diff-on-untracked-files)

Comment: What about `git add -N .; git diff HEAD..HEAD~1` ?

Comment: @SajibKhan: actually, it turns out that works (so I deleted the comment). But there's a somewhat better way for this particular purpose (script).

Comment: hm, it's ok @torek

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have suggested, you can use `git add -N` to add dummy entries to the index.  Running:

```
git diff <hash>
```

will then compare the given  to the current work-tree, using the existing index (which now has entries for the untracked files) to decide which work-tree versions to compare to the given `<hash>` (`<hash>` may be a commit ID, or a tree ID, or a branch name, or anything that Git can resolve to a tree).  But this does mess with the index, and as you said, you:

> would like to do this in a maximally atomic and robust way

The trick is to use, instead, a *temporary* index.

The initial commit here has files `bar` and `foo`; the second commit has file `foo` removed.  The current work-tree has `foo` resurrected and a new file, as shown in `git status --short`.

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 11b241c (HEAD -> master) remove foo
* 8527327 initial
$ git status --short
A  diffscript
A  foo
```

Note that the initial commit is `8527327`, which is what we pass to `diffscript` as an argument:

```
$ ./diffscript 8527327
diff --git a/diffscript b/diffscript
new file mode 100755
index 0000000..8d5c978
--- /dev/null
+++ b/diffscript
@@ -0,0 +1,6 @@
+#! /bin/sh
+export GIT_INDEX_FILE=$(mktemp) || exit
+rm -f $GIT_INDEX_FILE
+trap "rm -f $GIT_INDEX_FILE" 0 1 2 3 15
+git add -A
+git diff ${1:-HEAD}
index 3ec370c..d319048 100644
--- a/foo
+++ b/foo
@@ -1 +1 @@
-I am a foo
+I was foo, am now resurrected
```

This `diffscript` defaults to diffing against `HEAD`.  Hence, if we run it with no arguments, we would compare commmit `11b241c` to the index/work-tree (because we `git add -A` it *mostly* does not matter whether we compare to index or work-tree, at this point: they are essentially the same, modulo `.gitignore` directives).

The `trap ...` line makes sure we remove the temporary index, whether the script is terminated by ^C (signal 2, SIGINT), or a network disconnect (signal 1, SIGHUP) or a QUIT (signal 3, SIGQUIT) or TERMINATE (signal 15, SIGTERM), or just exits normally (0, not a signal, just normal termination).

Annoyingly, Git insists that the file either not exist at all, or have an index file signature—an empty file is not allowed—so we remove the temp file `mktemp` makes, so that the `git add` step can create it with the right signature.

Comment: I don't get it. The `diffscript` just adds everything to the index and then leaves it there

Comment: Note the line `GIT_INDEX_FILE=$(mktemp) || exit`. It doesn't use *the* index, it uses some *other* index, which we remove when done. *The* index is left untouched! But, needs a bug fix: `export`! (I didn't test it properly)

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't realize that GIT_INDEX_FILE has a function. But now I get "index file smaller than expected"

Comment: Ugh, another bug, will fix. BTW, another technique is to copy the "real" index file to the temporary, before running any `git add`s. This is how `git commit --include <paths>` works internally, for instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @torek: the year is now 2022, hasn't there been extra options added to `git diff` or `git diff-index` to get that diff ?

Comment: @LeGEC: nope. It doesn't seem to be needed all that often (I've never needed it myself at least)...

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at:

`git add --intent-to-add` (same as `git add -N`)

This will only append an empty entry to the index, but not the files themselves. The difference will be seen when using the diff command.

GIT documentation:

> **--intent-to-add**
>
> This is useful for, among other things, showing the unstaged content
> of such files with git diff and committing them with git commit -a.> Record only the fact that the path will be added later. An entry for
> the path is placed in the index with no content.

Comment: Goes in the right direction, but is not as automatic and atomic as I'd wish. (Would require to add all untracked files, remember them, and later reset them again)