# Why does `git checkout -m` succeed without merge?

Tags: git

*Git Pocket Guide* says

> Git ignores untracked files while switching branches, **unless the
>   file exists in the target branch**; then it aborts, even if the versions
>   in the working tree and destination branch are the same. You can
>   **use the --merge option to get around this without having to delete
>   the untracked file**, only to have Git restore it a moment later. The
>   merge operation results in the same file, in this case.

On branch  `master`, I have a tracked file `hellofile`

```
$ git branch 
  feature2
* master
$ cat hellofile 
hello
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

On branch `feature2`, it has no file `hellofile`, and I create it but leave it untracked

```
$ git checkout feature2
$ ls
common  reader  README  writer
$ echo "world" > hellofile
```

I then try to checkout `master`. It is understandable that `git checkout` will fail, but with `-m` succeed. But why does `git checkout -m`  succeed without merge? (I am expecting a file `hellofile` with marked conflict)

```
$ git checkout master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    hellofile
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
$ git branch
* feature2
  master

$ git checkout -m master
error: Dirty index: cannot merge (dirty: f2f hellofile)
Switched to branch 'master'
$ cat hellofile 
hello
```

Comment: If you continue reading the book, the next section is titled *Losing Your Head*, which probably implies the current section has something dangerous. Maybe the untracked file is ignored in the 3-way merge.

Comment: My question would be, you already said you're willing to deal with minor conflicts, why _not_ let the checkout succeed and pop a note, even if this is a slightly different kind of conflict than merges usually deal with?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `hellofile` is not tracked in `feature2`, yet exists in `master`. `-m` is designed for both branches having some change on a tracked file. Now, this change may or may not be staged, but is tracked in our working tree. Contrarily, I hope it makes sense that if both branches has added and committed some version of the file, we would have standard conflict.

If the file is not at least *tracked* in both branches, then the 3-Way merge seems to resolve the conflict as a `git checkout --ours`... more on this in the discussion section.

That is, in doing this in your example,

```
$ echo "world" > hellofile
$ git checkout -m master
```

you are effectively (not actually) saying to disregard changes in the current working directories' un-tracked file. If however, you had been tracking `hellofile` on both branches and did your modification,

```
$ `echo "world" > hellofile"
$ `git add hellofile`
```

you would have gotten a conflict which looked more like this:

```
<<<<<<< master
hello
=======
world
>>>>>>> local
```

I am going to assume that is what you were going for; it was correctly marked as a merge conflict. Yet, your change was brought across both branches without being committed.

---

### Discussion

[The documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout--m) doesn't say this is intended, but that your problem is clearly the behavior. I think this is probably an oversight/bug on their part. What they seem to mean, is

> "However, with this option, a three-way merge between the current branch, your *indexed files*, and the new branch is done, and you will be on the new branch."

After reading this post: [Can I use git diff on untracked files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855767/can-i-use-git-diff-on-untracked-files), I am going to assume that what is actually happening in the merge scheme is that the working directory file doesn't actually have a valid blob in the index to be considered something to merge, and so is for all intents and purposes, "disregarded".

Edit: Here is a question that was just asked, with a similar sort of conundrum: [Why does git checkout <<file>> not work when the same file is in index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221750/why-does-git-checkout-file-not-work-when-the-same-file-is-in-index)