# How to show content of all untracked files in git in the terminal

Tags: bash, git, shell

When I do `git status`, I will see a list of files that are tracked and not tracked.
e.g.

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   ../TODO.md

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        src/api/x.py
        src/apps/x.py
        src/schemas/x.py
        ../frontend/src/components/Notes/x.tsx

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

And if I wanted to see the content of the already tracked files I can do `git diff` or `git diff --staged`

However though, I'd like an easy to way to see the full file contents of only all the untracked files that are not already gitignored (output format should be similar to what I'd see if I ran `git diff` where it shows the (changed) contents in a list).

What is the best way to do this? Do I need to actually use a for loop in bash ([ex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/632910/find-a-list-of-files-and-echo-the-file-name-and-cat-the-file-contents)) after parsing the git output, or is there a better way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use git diff on untracked files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855767/can-i-use-git-diff-on-untracked-files)

Comment: Generate file lists with `git ls-files`, it's got an `-o` option to list for other, untracked files in the work tree. How you view them is up to you,

Comment: @rfkortekaas ah yes that answers my question! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
git ls-files --others -z | xargs -0 cat
```

This lists the untracked files (others) using null char delimiters to avoid problems with spaces and other special chars and sends it to `xargs` which is also told to use null delimiters.

See [git ls-files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) for other options.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.