# git: Can I stash an untracked file without adding it to the index?

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, git-stash

A related question [How do you stash an untracked file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835501/git-how-do-you-stash-an-untracked-file) was answered with "track the file."  This doesn't work for my particular needs, however.

I'm trying to stash everything that isn't in the index with `git stash save --keep-index` so that I can validate the index in my pre-commit hook. The idea is from the "Testing partial commits" example of the git-stash man page. I want to make sure that what I'm actually committing passes the tests and not just whats in the working directory. Here's what I have so far:

```
echo "Running tests on the staging area."
git stash save --keep-index
# configure, build, run tests, clean
git stash pop; true
```

This seems to work until I have untracked files in my working directory which don't get stashed. Some searching resulted in a feature request from two years ago: [Option to save untracked and/or ignored files in stash](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=461485), but nothing else.

Should I be using stash at all? Perhaps theres a better way involving temporary branches or something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I answered on the related question, the answer is now YES:

As of git 1.7.7, `git stash` accepts the `--include-untracked` option to include untracked files in your stash.

```
git stash --include-untracked
```

Or you can use the short `-u` option.

```
git stash -u
```

Answer (score 2):

No, git stash will only "record the current state of the working directory and the index".  So  stashing won't pickup your untracked files.

Switching to a temporary branch and tracking the untracked files there, as you suggest, seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: I suppose my definition of "working directory" differs from that of the git developers.

I've solved my problem by using git-checkout-index to a temporary directory and building there. I'd still rather use git-stash if possible, however.

Comment: That's definitely a strange definition of "working directory". I would also consider new files to be part of my working directory.