# Git: list only "untracked" files (also, custom commands)

Tags: git, git-status, git-rm, git-stage, git-ls-files

Is there a way to use a command like `git ls-files` to show only untracked files?

The reason I'm asking is because I use the following command to process all deleted files:

```
git ls-files -d | xargs git rm
```

I'd like something similar for untracked files:

```
git some-command --some-options | xargs git add
```

I was able to find the `-o` option to `git ls-files`, but this isn't what I want because it also shows ignored files.  I was also able to come up with the following long and ugly command:

```
git status --porcelain | grep '^??' | cut -c4- | xargs git add
```

It seems like there's got to be a better command I can use here.  And if there isn't, how do I create custom git commands?

Comment: Could you elaborate why do you need `git ls-files -d | xargs git rm`?

Comment: That removes all files that git notices are missing.   My question was about how to do a related operation - add all files that git isn't currently tracking.  I would usually do both of these after renaming, combining, and/or splitting my code files.

Comment: If they're missing, then aren't they already deleted? Unless... you pulled from somewhere else and then you're trying to synch with remote... I think I get it.

Comment: I've tested all answers,if there's empty untracked folder, no one can find it.

Comment: @kittygirl this is correct.  Because `git` works only on files, it does not have any way of tracking empty folders.  Try `find . -type d -empty` instead.

Answer (score 711, accepted):

To list untracked files try:

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

If you need to pipe the output to `xargs`, it is wise to mind white spaces using `git ls-files -z` and `xargs -0`:

```
git ls-files -z -o --exclude-standard | xargs -0 git add
```

Nice alias for adding untracked files:

```
au = !git add $(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard)
```

**Edit:** For reference: [git-ls-files](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files)

Comment: Perfect!  What does the `!` mean at the beginning of the alias line, or where is that documented?

Comment: @takeshin How to get only parent directory names? not subfolders. Means in these untracked files: /P/a/files , /P/a/images , /P/a/ /P/ , ... - I just wanna list /P/

Comment: In what situation would you need the alias though? `git add *` will do the same thing: add all untracked files excluding the standard (files who's paths are covered in `.gitignore`).

Comment: I prefer my alias to work consistently in all directories in the repo (the ls-files command only shows changed files in the current tree), so I have `[alias] lso = "!f() { cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel); git ls-files -o; }; f"`

Comment: @takeshin,does it include files tracked by git-lfs ?

Comment: @takeshin,this answer ignore  empty folders.

Comment: @WeAreAllMonica It is an alias to put in your .gitconfig.  So the ! means run the comand in subshell.

Answer (score 87):

If you just want to remove untracked files, do this:

*warning this will remove all of you untracked files including directories*

```
git clean -df
```

add `x` to that if you want to also include specifically ignored files.  I use `git clean -dfx` a *lot* throughout the day.

You can create custom git by just writing a script called `git-whatever` and having it in your path.

Comment: It's much more common that I want to *add* all untracked files (for example, after I move some things around).  In any case, thanks for the tip about custom commands.  Where is that mechanism documented?

Comment: Just do `git add -A` or `git add -u` (depending on which makes more sense to you)

Comment: and "git clean -dfxn" for a dry run by adding "n"

Comment: Add `-i` to make it interactive. Can't recommend that enough.

Answer (score 67):

`git add -A -n`
will do what you want. `-A` adds all untracked *and modified* files to the repo, `-n` makes it a `dry-run` where the add isn't performed but the status output is given listing each file that *would* have been added.

Comment: This is a great answer! Note that it excludes files in `.gitignore` files, which is usually what we want, but if not, `git add -fAn`.

Comment: This seems like the best answer.

Comment: This is THE best answer. It explicitly tells user what it would do (without doing it) and giving chance to review it before actually adding it. Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: It also lists modified files.

Comment: nice, but I get it wrapped: `add '$file'`. Whereas `git ls-files --exclude-standard -o` gives a bare output, piping hot.

Comment: Just to say it clearly: This is not the searched-for answer. The original poster was looking for the bare file names without any ornamental characters (in order to process them by other commands), and without showing modified files, too.

Answer (score 48):

```
git status -u
```

will list all untracked files.  Long form:

```
git status --untracked-files
```

Comment: how about a non-recursive version of that?

Comment: Unfortunately, it also lists file ignored thru .gitignore files.

Comment: This is the only answer that showed my ignored files on initial commit, but I had to add `--ignored` to the `git status -u` command

Comment: This *also* shows modified files.  So, not an answer to the question: *only* show untracked files.

Comment: this also outputs extra lines such as `On branch ...`, `Untracked files:` and `(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)` before as well as `nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)` after the actual file list - which must be removed if the output is to be used as input for another command

Comment: @ssc add the flag `--short` to make that task much simpler

Answer (score 33):

The accepted answer crashes on filenames with space. I'm at this point not sure how to update the alias command, so I'll put the improved version here:

```
git ls-files -z -o --exclude-standard | xargs -0 git add
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, because it provides the path of each file to perform an action (like git add) on them afterwards

Answer (score 11):

I know its an old question, but in terms of listing untracked files I thought I would add another one which also lists untracked folders:

You can used the git clean operation with -n (dry run) to show you which files  it will remove (including the .gitignore files) by:

`git clean -xdn`

This has the advantage of showing **all files** and **all folders** that are not tracked. Parameters:

- `x` - Shows all untracked files (including ignored by git and others, like build output etc...)
- `d` - show untracked directories
- `n` - and most **importantly!** - dryrun, i.e. don't actually delete anything, just use the clean mechanism to display the results.

It can be a little bit unsafe to do it like this incase you forget the `-n`. So I usually alias it in git config.

Comment: Why is git output so annoyingly human-readable? The proposed answer prints "Would remove" before each filename, so it's not usable for the OP's use case without further grepping.

Answer (score 9):

When looking for files to potentially add.  The output from `git show` does that but it also includes a lot of other stuff.  The following command is useful to get the same list of files but without all of the other stuff.

```
 git status --porcelain | grep "^?? " | sed -e 's/^[?]* //'
```

This is useful when combined in a pipeline to find files matching a specific pattern and then piping that to `git add`.

```
git status --porcelain | grep "^?? "  | sed -e 's/^[?]* //' | \
egrep "\.project$|\.settings$\.classfile$" | xargs -n1 git add
```

Answer (score 9):

All previous answers which I checked would list the files to be committed, too.
Here is a simple and easy solution that only lists files which are not yet in the
repo and not subject to `.gitignore`.

```
git status --porcelain | awk '/^\?\?/ { print $2; }'
```

or

```
git status --porcelain | grep -v '\?\?'
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work well with files that have a space in their name

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a feature/problem with:

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

wanting to list only untracked files:
if untracked file is in a modified directory, file will not be listed

Answer (score -3):

I think this will do the same thing as the original poster intended:

`git add .`

Adding some caveats:

- You have run `git status` and confirmed your local directories are clean
- You have run `git diff` on each file reported in `git status`, and confirmed your changes are clean
- Your changes are covered with automated unit testing
- Your changes are covered with automated integration testing
- You have run the integration tests through a debugger, verifying the new behavior by white box observing the new code in action
- You have run all linting / code convention rules and they pass
- You have run all unit tests and they pass
- You have run all local integration tests, and they pass
- You have deployed your changes to an app review environment and manually tested them end to end in isolation from other changes
- You have merged latest from main branch and re-run all automated unit and integration testing, fixing any merge conflicts and test failures

Now, my friend, you are ready to `git add .` with impunity.

Comment: Every time you do `git/svn add .`, the kitten dies.

Comment: Heh, only if you've got a bunch of cruft in your local copies of remote branches ;)  Make local branches and you can `git add .` with impunity!

Comment: @Nakilon, that's why you configure `.gitignore` properly.  Still good to avoid `git add .`, though.  Better is `git add -u`.

Comment: Heh, been a long time @Nakilon and @Wildcard. Updated the answer for clarity, there are definitely some assumptions about developer workflow that can impact safe usage of `git add .`.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote. Nice list though. It kind of shows that you need to do a lot of stuff anyway to be sure that you are doing the things right and that's why staging files in more precise way than just `git add .` should not be considered like something tedious. That was my point. 2013? Bad that things don't really change -- people still do it and that's the unobvious but real half of the reason to have pull requests and code reviews. Like a fighting the symptoms. Downvotes were probably because you also have to do `git checkout .` before that to not add changes.