# Get a preview of "git add -u"?

Tags: git

I'm trying to write a .gitignore file. I'd like to get a preview of everything that would be added if I were to run "git add -u". Is that possible? Or, if I ran "git add -u", and some stuff got added that I don't want, can I undo the entire thing? Then I'll tweak my .gitignore some more and repeat.

Thanks

Comment: to be honest right now I'm to stupid to understand what 'git add --help' is saying about '-u'. What differences would we (eventually) see in 'git status' before and after applying 'git add -u' ? And what if we used 'git add' instead'?

Comment: Could this be helpful for your use case (How do I undo 'git add' before commit?) ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/348170/2623045

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

`git add -n`

.. which is the `--dry-run` short switch :)

Edit: from the root of the repository, try:

`git add -n .`

If you were to mistakenly add files that were supposed to be ignored, and you didn't catch it in the dry run, you'd just use:

`git reset HEAD --`

.. which would essentially unstage the files.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the same preview won't work with an interractive add.

Git 2.32 (Q2 2021) is now clearer: "[`git add -i --dry-run`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/47fa10661746e32cbc76a88392e1cda38def27c6/Documentation/git-add.txt#L82)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--i))</sup> does *not* `dry-run`, which was surprising.
The combination of options has taught to error out.

See [commit a1989cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1989cf7b8d062960b6f8de00435711c45b95285) (05 May 2021) by [Øystein Walle (`Osse`)](https://github.com/Osse).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 47fa106](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47fa10661746e32cbc76a88392e1cda38def27c6), 14 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`add`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1989cf7b8d062960b6f8de00435711c45b95285): die if both `--dry-run` and `--interactive` are given
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Øystein Walle</sup>

> The interactive machinery does not obey `--dry-run`.
> Die appropriately if both flags are passed.

---

And: With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), stop "[`git add --dry-run`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6ffb5fc06940ebb312b5cb010246e27c1b6aead0/Documentation/git-add.txt#L70)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---dry-run))</sup> from creating new blob and tree objects.

See [commit e578d03](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e578d0311d7b19ebd8cdadc6941f2aa060b7a850) (12 Oct 2021) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6ffb5fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ffb5fc06940ebb312b5cb010246e27c1b6aead0), 25 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`add`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e578d0311d7b19ebd8cdadc6941f2aa060b7a850): don't write objects with --dry-run
>
> <sup>Reported-by: git.mexon@spamgourmet.com</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> When the option `--dry-run/-n` is given, "[`git add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e578d0311d7b19ebd8cdadc6941f2aa060b7a850/Documentation/git-add.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup> doesn't change the index, but still writes out new object files.
> Only hash the latter without writing instead to make the run as dry as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found that

```
git add -n .
```

also is showing modified files while

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

does not.

For now for me the second one is the prefered way previewing/testing .gitignore.

Also I found some comments in posts discouraging to use 'add .' at all and prefer 'add -u' .

I also tried

```
git add -u -n
```

but from my experience this is showing modified files only.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888722/2623045

BTW: git submodules seem to me to be an extra use case in this context (don't know if additional switches to 'git ls-files' can reflect that)