# git detect if there are untracked files quickly

Tags: git

Is there a way to quickly detect if there are any untracked files?

I can [list all of the untracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801321/git-list-only-untracked-files-also-custom-commands) with

```
git ls-files --other --directory --exclude-standard
```

But this is slow if there are many untracked files.  Is there something like `git diff -q` where the exit status determines whether or not any untracked files exist?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you have what you want when you've seen the first untracked file, quit right then.

If you're on GNU/anything

```
git ls-files --other --directory --exclude-standard | sed q1
```

will set rc1 if there are any

Otherwise,

```
anyuntracked() {
    return `git ls-files -o --directory --exclude-standard | sed q | wc -l`
}
anyuntracked
```

will do the same job

Comment: To get results more in line with `git status`, add `--no-empty-directory`.

Comment: I don't think this works at all. If you benchmark this command it's exactly the same speed with and without sed. I suspect that git is not flushing the output until all of it is available.

Comment: @user3467349 I don't think the few dozen  filenames it takes to fill a buffer add enough time to bother many people, he said "many", but if you've got some weird layout that scatters few untracked files across many directories or something there's always the `stdbuf` command to force linebuffering on the ls-files stdout.

Comment: `-d` will return the list of deleted files; it's not a synonym for `--directory`

Comment: @tavnab Thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

`git status` will notify you of any untracked files.

Example output:

```
remco@Prosperpine ~/code/Sick-Beard (master) $ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   init.osx
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: I think `git ls-files` is still faster than `git status`

Comment: Yes, as a matter for fact you are right! I timed both commands on a test set of 100000 new files. `git status` took `real:0m0.927s`, while `ls-files` only took `real:0m0.468s`. (Not much of an answer, but perhaps good to know)