# .gitignore: track a single file in an ignored directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I am trying to add a single non-tracked file to a repo within a directory that is in a `.gitignore`.

I am using the following:

```
parent/child/*
parent/child/child-02/*
!parent/child/child-02/file.txt
```

This usually works on a first-child directory but not in the format above.  What Am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be to force add the single file. Once tracked, git will continue tracking the file irrespective of whether it is ignored or not in any of your `.gitignore`.

So simply using the below will work:

```
git add -f parent/child/child-02/file.txt 
git commit -m "added file.txt"
```

---

If you really want to correct your `.gitignore` file, you will have to add one more rule (`!parent/child/child-02`). This essentially tells `git` to not ignore the `child-02` directory, and so the subsequent rules work:

```
parent/child/*
!parent/child/child-02
parent/child/child-02/*
!parent/child/child-02/file.txt
```

---

***DEMO***

```
test $ mkdir repo && cd repo && git init
repo $ mkdir -p parent/child/child-02
repo $ touch file parent/file parent/child/file parent/child/child-02/file.txt
repo $ cat .gitignore 
parent/child/*
!parent/child/child-02
parent/child/child-02/*
!parent/child/child-02/file.txt
repo $ git add .
repo $ git status
        new file:   .gitignore
        new file:   file
        new file:   parent/child/child-02/file.txt
        new file:   parent/file
```

Comment: `parent/child/*
!parent/child/child-02
parent/child/child-02/*
!parent/child/child-02/file.txt` Is what I was needing - Thnx!

Comment: I have to mention, that in `git status` you'll see whole directory `parent` marked as untracked. This confused me, so I used `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3801554/1713660) to be sure I add only one file