# git grep in only untracked files

Tags: git, grep, command

I would like to grep inside `Untracked files` and in files from `Changes not staged for commit` but not in the rest.

Is it possible to achieve this with `git grep` ?

Answer (score 4):

To list untracked files try:

`git ls-files --others --exclude-standard`

To grep in untracked files.

`grep 'search' $(git ls-files -m --others --exclude-standard)`

replace the **search** word with your search string.

From man-page:

```
git-ls-files - Show information about files in the index and the working tree

-m, --modified
           Show modified files in the output
-o, --others
           Show other (i.e. untracked) files in the output
--exclude-standard
       Add the standard git exclusions: .git/info/exclude, .gitignore in each directory, and the user’s global exclusion file.
```

Credits goes to

- [Git: list only "untracked" files (also, custom commands)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801321/git-list-only-untracked-files-also-custom-commands)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20262/how-do-i-pass-a-list-of-files-to-grep

Comment: Will not work with the file names contain special characters.