# how to take a backup of untracked files in the git

Tags: git

I have a situation wherein I have to take a huge list of un-tracked file and copy it to some backup folder.

I know we can stash un-tracked file using `git stash -u` but I don't want 
that.

I just want it to be copied to local folder in filesystem.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [list files that are untracked (and not ignored)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3801554/6309)

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

From there, you can copy each one to a backup location.

Comment: Thank you for reply. `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard | xargs tar cvzf backup.tar.gz` I could tar them and put it to another folder. But somehow cp copies only files and not a folder structure. Anyways tar works as well.