# How to list files not tracked by git and sort them according to modification time?

Tags: git

I want to list the files that are not part of git repository and were recently modified. If there are no spaces in file names and `git status` returns only `#` before untracted files, then I can do:

```
ls -ltrhd `git status | awk 'NF==2 {print $2}'`
```

However, making this more universal (e.g., if there are spaces in file names), then it gets complicated. Is there a way to get the same output directly from `git`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: list only "untracked" files (also, custom commands)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801321/git-list-only-untracked-files-also-custom-commands)

Comment: No. The solutions there list contents of subdirs and I don't want that (option `-d` of `ls`).

Comment: @rpoleski check the docs for [git ls-files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) : there is a `--directory` option

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the same output directly from git?

Nope. You can handle spaces in filenames by setting `IFS` though, and `git status` is doing some hidden recursing, to not do any of it you can use `find`'s depth cutoff:

```
(IFS=$'\n'; ls -ltrh $(git ls-files -o `find -maxdepth 1 ! -type d`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @LeGEC. The solution still requires `ls`, but does not depend on `awk`:

```
ls -ltrhd `git ls-files -o --directory --exclude-standard`
```