# With using Git, `git status` will output paths of untracked files and directories. How do I get exactly these paths?

Tags: git

Example:

```sh
$ git --version
git version 2.33.0.windows.2

$ ls --recursive
.:
untracked-directory/  untracked-file.txt

./untracked-directory:
untracked-file-1-in-untracked-directory.txt  untracked-file-2-in-untracked-directory.txt

$ git status
On branch main
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        untracked-directory/
        untracked-file.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

How do I get the paths in the "Untracked files" section of the output of `git status`?

Answer (score 2):

`git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --directory`[a] seems to always give the paths that `git status` gives for "Untracked files".

From the same example in the question body:

```sh
$ git --version
git version 2.33.0.windows.2

$ ls --recursive
.:
untracked-directory/  untracked-file.txt

./untracked-directory:
untracked-file-1-in-untracked-directory.txt  untracked-file-2-in-untracked-directory.txt

$ git status
On branch main
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        untracked-directory/
        untracked-file.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --directory
untracked-directory/
untracked-file.txt
```

### Note

[a] `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --directory` was adapted from `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` of [the accepted answer of "*Git: list only "untracked" files (also, custom commands)*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3801554) by trying out `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` from that answer, noticing it wasn't the exact paths that `git status` reports, and then somehow I got to [the documentation for `git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files), searched the page for "directory", and then I found the `--directory` option, and then I tried it out, and it gave the paths that `git status` gives, and I have yet to find an example where both `git status` and `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --directory` disagree.

Comment: Just for fun, I tracked down [the last version of git where `git-status` was still a shell script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.1.6/git-status.sh) and sure enough, it used `git-ls-files -z --others --directory --exclude-per-directory=.gitignore` (the `-z` is just formatting with zero-bytes for easier post-processing in the rest of the script). There's no guarantee things haven't changed in the following 15 years to introduce new edge-cases, though!

Comment: @IMSoP This is fun! I'm wondering if it possible to find things in the source of current Git to add sufficient confidence that `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --directory`'s output and `git status`'s "Untracked files" output will always be the same. Based on `git ls-files -h` describing `--directory` with "show 'other' directories' names only", which lead to [this search of Git's source](https://github.com/git/git/search?q=%22show+%27other%27+directories%27+names+only%22), which lead to [continued in future comment]

Comment: [continued from past comment] [this search](https://github.com/git/git/search?q=DIR_SHOW_OTHER_DIRECTORIES), which presented both of the files [wt-status.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/99c99ed8259bf070cd8ae7b51a94904b7cf5c161/wt-status.c) and [ls-files.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/99c99ed8259bf070cd8ae7b51a94904b7cf5c161/builtin/ls-files.c), it seems that perhaps it might be possible to find one or more similarities, between ls-files.c and wt-status.c, that will give the earlier desired confidence I mentioned. At this moment I haven't found any clear confidence booster.

Answer (score 1):

`git status -uall` will show all the files, rather than summarizing them.  Note that this requires the word `all` to be joined to the `-u` part.

This works even in quite old versions of Git.  Newer Git versions have a `status.showUntrackedFiles` setting so that you can set this to default to showing all files.  Note that it takes longer to show all files: when Git can abbreviate like this, Git can short-circuit the work it would have to do to *find* all the file names.  (How *much* longer is very working-tree and OS and file system dependent.)