# lost git stash changes

Tags: git, git-stash

So here's what happened:
I was on a branch 'A' and did a Git stash on that branch. Then I switched to another branch 'B'. I navigated back to Branch 'A' but did not do a Git stash pop. I switched to the master branch and then back to branch 'A'. I am trying to go a git stash pop now but cant seem to get my changes back.. I need to recover that code but whenever I do a git stash pop, my file changes are not listed. I did not commit any code.

Is there a way to recover the changes that I made? would really appreciate any help in this regards.

Comment: try "git stash list" to see what stashes you have available.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Stashes should be viewable via

```
git stash list
```

or

```
gitk --all
```

also, `git stash` does not stash untracked files. If you did this and subsequently did a `git checkout --force` of another branch to overwrite untracked files with tracked ones in another branch, you have lost that content. The recommended way to stash is with

```
git stash -u
```

This will prevent losses of this type.

Comment: after `git stash list` you can apply specific stashes by index number. For example `git stash apply 1` will apply the line that starts with `stash@{1}`

Comment: You saved my project))

Comment: What id I dont find my changes in the stash list?

Comment: `git stash` from branch `main` followed by `git stash branch newbranch` followed by `git checkout main` caused my stash to vanish. The checkout did not use `--force`.  Maybe that is a git bug or limitation?

Answer (score 47):

We also faced the same issue. So, here is how we recovered the lost changes:

1. Go back to branch B.

   > git checkout B
2. Use `git reflog` option to mange reflog information.

   > git reflog --all

   **Output:**

   > f332d5c refs/stash@{0}: WIP on B: aa1d0c1 xyz commit message
3. Now, switch to branch A using `git checkout A`
4. Finally, to recover your lost changes.

   > git stash apply **f332d5c**

Comment: Had access to commit, but lost my stash. Recovered my work `git stash apply`. Thanks!

Comment: @Mitkins thanks so much, I've also encountered this and `git stash apply` works for me!

Comment: you, frankly, just saved my last 2 weeks in combination with http://effectif.com/git/recovering-lost-git-commits. THANKS!

Comment: I managed to lose my stash, TimeMachine wasn't enabled on my new Mac. Remote backup was no help. Who knew you could get a lost stash back. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me. In short, check to make sure you didn't accidentally push the new files to the other branch.

Here's what happened to me: I stashed my stuff, switched from 'dev' to 'master' to do a hotfix quick. When I pushed my hotfix to master, I didn't notice that I also added my new files that were meant for dev to the master branch--I too assumed stash included those files.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have lost my git stash changes but my theory as to why is that the changes were already applied.

I did something like this:

```
> git pull
conflict detected; stash or commit your changes first
(list of conflicting files)

> git stash
> git pull
success (tons of changes pulled)

> git stash pop
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Dropped refs/stash@{0}

> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

> git stash list
(nothing)

> git stash pop
No stash entries found.
```

I think my pull already included the same changes that were in the stash, so the stash had no effect. At least I hope that's what happened.