# How to switch branch without commit changes

Tags: git, git-checkout

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   wp-content/plugins/bznrd-inventory/ReduxFramework/extensions/location/location/field_location.php
        modified:   wp-content/plugins/bznrd-inventory/js/admin.js
```

Comment: an alternative would be to stash your changes first, then switch to another branch, then continue what you need to do on that other branch. if you want to go back to your changes you can pop it back

Comment: Sometimes you can switch branches anyway, even though you have uncommitted changes. Sometimes you can't. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/22082307/1256452

Answer (score 3):

2 options:

`git stash` to apply your changes to a stash, which you can later restore with `git stash apply`, or

`git checkout -b wip-branch && git add . && git commit -m "wip" && git checkout <current_branch>`

Comment: You can also use `git stash pop` after `git stash` to apply the changes and delete the stash from the stash stack