# Committing local changes after branches are switched

Tags: git, smartgit

I am supposed to work on git branch A, I however was unconsciously working on branch B. After noticing, my intention now is to switch to branch A without committing to branch B. After switching to branch A, I can do my commits. How do I achieve this using smart git?

PS: I have not committed to branch B at all

Comment: Have you already committed anything to branch B that was supposed to be on A?

Comment: @TTT No, I haven't

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git switch branch without discarding local changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082307/git-switch-branch-without-discarding-local-changes)

Comment: @TTT no, the questions are different, I haven't committed changes in the wrong branch at all in my own case. I noticed before making commits

Comment: The fact that you didn't commit yet is what makes it a duplicate. ;)

Comment: To clarify, in both your situation and the question I linked to, you have some pending changes which you want to commit to some other branch instead of the one you are currently on. The answer below describes exactly what you need to do, and so does the answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not committed your changes to branch-b, then [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) should work:

```
> git stash
> git checkout branch-a
> git stash apply
```