# Lost changes after stash+pop with Git

Tags: git, git-stash

Here is my problem:

1. After doing some changes in my project, I executed `git stash`, but I did not execute `git add .` before.
2. I then removed one folder I was working in before doing `git stash`.
3. Finally, when I wanted to `pop` the changes I found that the folder was not there.

What happened? Is there any solution?

Thanks again.

Comment: try `git stash apply`, which works for me. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147042/lost-git-stash-changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man git stash`:

```
git-stash - Stash the changes in a dirty working directory away
```

If there were untracked files (files you never "git added" to the repo), then they will not be stashed. So if you deleted the folder, you lost your work.

For the next time, you can consider using `git stash --include-untracked` (see `man git stash`).

Comment: Alternatively, do `git add .` before stashing to include untracked files.