# git stash - No local changes to save but untracked files

Tags: git, git-stash

I'd like to stash some Untracked files. I tried:

```
$ git stash
```

which gave

```
No local changes to save
```

Running `git status` gives:

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    dir/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you stash an untracked file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835501/how-do-you-stash-an-untracked-file)

Answer (score 8):

You need to stash untracked files. Stash with `--include-untracked` flag.
 Or, `Add` first then, do stash.

```
$ git stash --include-untracked

OR,
$ git add .      # add untracked files
$ git stash
```

Comment: Note that a stash that includes untracked files may be harder to restore later (should one wish to do so).