# cleaning working tree from untracked files and folders without losing them

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

sometimes while working on git repo i get in that situation where i have added new files after commit then i needed to `checkout` a previous commit the problem is when doing so i stuck with those new files i have created. so is there any way to clean those new untracked files and still be able to retrieve them after resting the **HEAD** and back to **master**?

i tried to stage everything and then `stash` all of it, running `clean`, and finally `checkout` whatever commit i want but this has the drawback of manually trying to unstage all the file that i don't want to be tracked be git

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835501/how-do-you-stash-an-untracked-file

Comment: See the linked duplicate for a traditional method, but consider (in modern Git at least) using `git worktree add` instead.