# Is it possible to use git stash command from Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-stash

I'm using Visual Studio 2017's Team Explorer to work with a `git` repository.

Every time I'm uses the `git stash` or `git stash pop`, I need to open the Git Bash console and navigate to my project folder and run the commands.

Is there any way to stash within Visual Studio (2017)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Yes**

**Git Stash:**

Git stash temporarily shelves (or stashes) changes you've made to your working copy so you can work on something else, and then come back and re-apply them later on. Stashing is handy if you need to quickly switch context and work on something else, but you're mid-way through a code change and aren't quite ready to commit.

[image]

**Stashing is available in VS 2019 and later versions.**

1. Go to Git changes window `Ctrl + Alt + F7`
2. Now press the drop down key near `Commit All` or `Commit staged` button to see the stashing options

**Option 2:**
You can use this option `Stash All and Keep Staged (--keep-index)` by default

[image]

**Option 1:**
Only if you want to stash untracked files like `Git ignored files` or `Files which are not included into project` then go for this option

[image]

You can keep/save multiple stashes with description like below:

[image]

**Retrieving a stash:**
You have two options, either to Apply or Pop.

`Apply` will retrieve the stash but wont delete the stash but `Pop` (Apply + Delete) will retrieve the stash and will also delete it.

[image]

Again, Under `Apply/Pop` you gonna see two options:

1. `Apply/Pop and restore staged (--index)`

Always use this option by default. This means while stashing if you had some files in changes and some files in staged, it'll be restored as such to changes and staged.

2. `Apply/Pop all as unstaged`

If you use this option, while stashing if you had some files in changes and some files in staged, all of these files now will be clubbed to Changes.

[image]

Answer (score 49):

**In VS2019** (not in VS2017 or before) in the Team Explorer window, you can select "Changes". Right next to the "Commit" button, there is a "Stash"...

Comment: @ikkentim you have to stage the changes first, then stash option appears besides commit button

Comment: @pca1987 Thanks a lot man, that was the key piece of information. Where to see the stash button :D

Answer (score 20):

In Visual Studio 2017 this feature is not available by default, but there's an extension for this:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vii.GitStashExtension