# Resetting a new file in staging area to working directory in Git

Tags: git

In Git I have checked out a new branch `branch b`and made multiple changes including edits, new files, folders etc. I need to revert back to an old branch `branch a` to make changes, so I want to stash all changes made in `branch b`. However I have some untracked files and folder in `branch b` so if I revert back to `branch a`, they follow as untracked files.

I attempted to add and then reset these untracked files with the intention of them moving to the working directory, but they revertedback to an untracked file (no surprise).

**Question**

How do I add these untracked files in `branch b` to the working directory ready to be stashed? (without committing)

Comment: Commit all on branch b, switch to branch a, work there, and when you're done you come back to branch a and unwind the commit you made earlier (with `git reset HEAD^`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you stash an untracked file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835501/how-do-you-stash-an-untracked-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested to use

```
git add --intend-to-add
```

to start tracking files without really adding/committing them.

From the manual:

> -N, --intent-to-add
>
> Record only the fact that the path will be added later. An entry for the path is placed in the index with no content. This is useful for, among other things, showing the unstaged content of such files with git diff and committing them with git commit -a.

Answer (score 1):

At branch b, add all the new files to the staging area, and do a save stash action, done.

After stashed, the new files will be saved to the stash, and removed from the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

First add the untracked file to stage area, using git add command.

```
git add /pathToUntrackedFile
git stash
```

If you don't want to stage it and keep them as untracked, you can use below commands

```
git stash -u # means --include-untracked
```

Now, you can switch branch a and work on it

```
git checkout branch a
```

In future, if you want to again work on branch b

```
git checkout branch b
git stash pop
```