# How can you git stash untracked files with a custom message?

Tags: git

How can I perform `git stash --include-untracked` with a custom message?

I've tried:

`git stash --include-untracked --message "Foo"`

and

`git stash "Foo" --include-untracked`

but both print a usage warning in Git 2.17.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operation you're looking for is `git stash push`; in this case you need the subcommand.  So you'd write `git stash push --include-untracked --message "Foo"`.

Comment: You can also do it like so: `git stash push -u -m 'Add your message here.'`. `-u` means to include untracked files and `-m` means message.

Answer (score 2):

In older versions of git (`< 2.13`) you need to use the `save` subcommand:

```
git stash save --include-untracked "Foo"
```

In newer version it is recommended to use the `push` subcommand:

```
git stash push --include-untracked --message "Foo"
```

---

Note: `stash save` is deprecated in favour of `stash push` since git version `2.16.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a branch for this.

If you don't want anybody to see this work, then just don't push it anywhere.

Comment: Yeah.   Commit,  don't stash.   Branches are essentially free and can be handled readily.  Stashes are tactically useless.

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.7.4

```
git stash save -u your message here
```